# error Requested product doesn't exist in magento2

Tags: magento2, product

when I am displaying product name through product id Requested product, doesn't exist an error is coming

```
<?php
    namespace Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;
    use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface; 
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
    use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
    use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
    class Products extends Column
    {
        protected $_ProductRepository;
        public function __construct(
            ContextInterface $context,
            UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
            ProductRepositoryInterface $ProductRepository,
            array $components = [],
            array $data = []){
            $this->_ProductRepository = $ProductRepository;
            parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
        }
        public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource){
            if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
                foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $productArr = [];
                $product  = $this->_ProductRepository->get($items["entity_id"]);
                foreach ($product->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
                $productArr[] = $item->getName(); //to get product name
            }  
                $items['products'] = implode(' - ', $productArr);
                unset($productArr);
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added answer It may help you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected your code Try this code it is working fine for me.

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as $key => $items) {
            $product = $this->_ProductRepository->getById($items["entity_id"]);
            $dataSource['data']['items'][$key]['entity_id'] = $product->getName(); //to get product name
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

AND this code

```
<column name="entity_id" class="Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: @AshishRamchandani, Try this

Comment: no chnages same error

Comment: @AshishRamchandani, Please check thoes Entity Id really exist?

Comment: yes it is in database it is stored

Comment: May I know what you actually doing with code, I mean the requirement?

Comment: i want to show the product name in custom admin grid through product id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89760/discussion-between-kunj-and-ashish-ramchandani).

Answer (score 1):

In productRepositry get method take first parameter as sku not product_id

please check in **ProductRepositoryInterface**

> public function get($**sku**, $editMode = false, $storeId = null, $forceReload = false);

here you have passed product_id

> $product  = $this->_ProductRepository->get(*$items["entity_id"]*);

please change below line:

> $product  = $this->_ProductRepository->get(*$items["entity_id"]*);

with this code(If you have product sku you can use get method):

> **$product  = $this->_ProductRepository->get(*$items["sku"]*);**

otherwise you can get product by id:

> **$product  = $this->_ProductRepository->getById(*$items["entity_id"]*);**

Comment: i can't get it is there any change in this code please do it

Comment: @AshishRamchandani i have added my answer please check

Comment: Undefined index: sku in /var/www/html/magento3/app/code/Magneto/PopupQuestion/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Products.php on line 25 error is coming

Comment: Can you add you ui-component code in question @AshishRamchandani

Comment: <column name="products" class="Magneto\PopupQuestion\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Products">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Products</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>