# Magento 2 exception Requested product doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, product, exception

My site running Magento 2.2.4 has been throwing a high number of exceptions: Requested product doesn't exist.

The error comes from method getById() in ProductRepository, line 273:

```
                throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Requested product doesn\'t exist'));
```

Looking for answers on the internet I saw messages such as lack of SKU on products and module relate issues, but sku's are all complete including flat and indexes. Neither I could find the buggy extensions installed.

There are no stack traces with the error message either.

Anyone can help me ? Thanks !

Comment: first check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/261917/85907 and second i think this problem is third party extension cross

Comment: Unfortunately it is not related to SKUs as we checked our db and all products have SKU. Other ideas ?